# Why Angular 8 CircleCI build fails while executing ng test --watch-false, with karma configured to singleRun=true?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, circleci

I'm migrating an open source project, [WUF](https://github.com/anvil-open-software/wuf), from Angular@7.2.0 to @8.2.14; its CircleCI CI/CD pipeline, [WUF](https://app.circleci.com/github/anvil-open-software/wuf/pipelines), which worked just fine on Angular@7.2.0, now fails after migrating to Angular@8.2.14 when attempting to execute the unit tests; the tests pass and then fails with the build attempts to run then multiple times.

I'm building on the `FM-736-ng8` branch.

The relevant portion of the CircleCI [config.yml](https://github.com/anvil-open-software/wuf/blob/FM-736-ng8/.circleci/config.yml) is:

```
         - run:
          name: Test WUF
          command: |
             ng test --watch=false --karmaConfig=src/karma.conf.circleci.js
```

The karma configuration file, [karma.conf.circleci.js](https://github.com/anvil-open-software/wuf/blob/FM-736-ng8/src/karma.conf.circleci.js), includes a flag to perform the test once and stop, with appears to have not effect. Again, worked just fine on Angular@7.2.0, now fails after migrating to Angular@8.2.14.

See below for the [most recent and relevant log](https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/github/anvil-open-software/wuf/399/output/110/0?file=true&allocation-id=5e279ad65d0ab00dbc8e747c-0-build%2F39AF271C) file snippets:

- Start of the build:

  0% compiling 10% building 0/0 modules 0 active

> Blockquote
>
> ```
> 10% building 0/0 modules 0 active
> 10% building 0/1 modules 1 active multi /root/wuf/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/es5-polyfills.js/root/wuf/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/es5-jit-polyfills.js/root/wuf/src/polyfills.ts
> 10% building 1/1 modules 0 active
> 10% building 1/1 modules 0 active
> 10% building 1/2 modules 1 active multi /root/wuf/src/polyfills.ts/root/wuf/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli files/models/jit-polyfills.js
> 10% building 2/2 modules 0 active
> 10% building 2/2 modules 0 active
> 10% building 2/3 modules 1 active multi /root/wuf/src/styles.scss/root/wuf/src/assets/dummydata/branding/branding.scss
> 10% building 3/3 modules 0 active START:
> 10% building 3/4 modules 1 active /root/wuf/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/es5-polyfills.js
> 10% building 4/4 modules 0 active
> ...
> ```

- End of the first unit test run:

> ```
> HomeComponent
>     + should create
>     Layout
>       + should have a view component
>       + should have a header component
>       + should have a content component
>       + should have a footer component
>   I18nAngularComponent
>     + should create
>     + should have cardinality paragraph showing 'no wolves'
>     + should have gender paragraph
>     + should have gender paragraph showing 'female.'
>     + should have pluralization paragraph
>     + should have pluralization paragraph showing 'has no wolves.'
>   I18nNgxTranslateComponent
>     + should create
>     + should create 
>
> Finished in 5.459 secs / 5.426 secs @ 00:50:40 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
>
> SUMMARY:
> + 68 tests completed
> # 1 test skipped
>
> 0% compiling
> 10% building 0/0 modules 0 active
> ```

Notice how the tests end, pass, and are re-launched. If you look at the log, you will observe that this repeats many times until it CircleCI kill it.

The expected behavior is for the unit tests to run once and stop!

Answer (score 0):

This is embarrassing! I have mono-repo project consisting of a number of `npm packages`, and an `application` showcasing them. When running unit tests using `ng test` the tests stop after running the application tests, without running the packages' tests.

When running unit tests using `ng test --watch false`, the application tests run, and then the package tests run; I misinterpreted the package errors as application test errors.

My mistake was to look at problems I was working on, the application tests, instead of at the areas other than my original focus. Quite embarrassing, but true.